# Why Can't I Filter my Dataset Based on Timeframe

Tags: r, date

I downloaded a [dataset from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/bike-sharing-demand/data?select=train.csv) and wanted to only include data from January through February of the month in my analysis.

Created the dataset using this

```
structure(list(datetime = c("1/20/2011 0:00", "1/20/2011 1:00", 
"1/20/2011 2:00", "1/20/2011 3:00", "1/20/2011 4:00", "1/20/2011 5:00"
), season = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), holiday = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), workingday = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), weather = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), temp = c(10.66, 10.66, 10.66, 10.66, 10.66, 9.84), atemp = c(11.365, 
13.635, 13.635, 12.88, 12.88, 11.365), humidity = c(56, 56, 56, 
56, 56, 60), windspeed = c(26.0027, 0, 0, 11.0014, 11.0014, 15.0013
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I installed Lubridate and Tidyverse and found the following code to help me filter.

```
test %>% filter(as_date(datetime) >= as_date("2011-01-20") & 
                   as_date(datetime) <= as_date("2011-02-20"))
```

Whenever I run the code i get the following error though.

Warning messages:
1: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

I tried to use the filter function, and I knew I needed to convert the character objects to                                                        dates, but I'm not sure why it still doesn't seem to be parsing properly. Perhaps, I need to change it to a date by reuploading the data?

Comment: We don't know what your `datetime` data looks like. Can you run `dput(head(test))` and put the output into your question? That will create a code recipe to recreate the first 6 rows of the table.

Comment: Please add reproducible data as code in the body of the question (ie, `dput(df)`), not as a link, as links become invalid, may be malicious, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify the correct time format explicitly:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

test |>
  filter(as_date(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") >= as_date("2011-01-20") & 
         as_date(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") <= as_date("2011-02-20"))
```

However, you might want to convert them to the `date` or `datetime` using `mutate` to preserve the types.

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 9
  datetime       season holiday workingday weather  temp atemp humidity windspeed
  <chr>           <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 1/20/2011 0:00      1       0          1       1 10.7   11.4       56      26.0
2 1/20/2011 1:00      1       0          1       1 10.7   13.6       56       0  
3 1/20/2011 2:00      1       0          1       1 10.7   13.6       56       0  
4 1/20/2011 3:00      1       0          1       1 10.7   12.9       56      11.0
5 1/20/2011 4:00      1       0          1       1 10.7   12.9       56      11.0
6 1/20/2011 5:00      1       0          1       1  9.84  11.4       60      15.0
```

See most formats here:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html